# Displaying Custom Post Types Through A Short Code

Tags: php, wordpress

I have made a new post type called 'football' (singular) 'footballs' (plural). I have a shortcode to display all of my posts in one page with the featured image ect here: http://www.freebetnodeposit.org/match-reports/ but can someone help me modify this code so that instead of displaying the 'posts' it displays the posts from the 'football' post type.

Heres the code:

```
<?php
function gp_posts($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'name' => '',
        'cats' => '',
        'images' => 'true',
        'image_width' => '533',
        'image_height' => '200',
        'image_wrap' => 'false',
        'cols' => '2',
        'per_page' => '6',
        'link' => 'both',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'desc',
        'offset' => '0',
        'content_display' => 'excerpt',
        'excerpt_length' => '400',
        'title' => 'true',
        'title_size' => '',
        'title_font' => '',
        'title_length' => '500',
        'meta' => 'true',
        'meta_author' => 'true',
        'meta_date' => 'true',
        'meta_cats' => 'true',
        'meta_tags' => 'true',
        'score' => 'true',
        'read_more' => 'true',
        'pagination' => 'true',
        'spacing' => 'spacing-normal',
        'header' => '',
        'rss' => '',
        'color' => ''       
    ),$atts));

    global $wp_query, $post, $dirname, $gp_settings;
    require(gp_inc . 'options.php');


    // Order By

    if($orderby == 'score') { 
        $orderby = 'meta_value_num';
        $meta_key = '_'.$dirname.'_total_score';
    } else {
        $orderby = $orderby;
        $meta_key = '';
    }


    // Title Size

    $title_weight = '';
    if($title_size != "") {
        if(preg_match('/^1[0-4]$/', $title_size)) {
            $title_weight = 'font-weight: bold; ';              
        }
    }
    if($title_size != "") {
        if(preg_match('/%/', $title_size) OR preg_match('/em/', $title_size) OR preg_match('/px/', $title_size)) {
            $title_size = 'font-size: '.$title_size.'; ';               
        } else {
            $title_size = 'font-size: '.$title_size.'px; ';     
        }
    } else {
        $title_size = "";
    }


    // Title Font

    if($title_font != "") {
        $title_font = 'font-family: '.$title_font.'; ';     
    } else {
        $title_font = "";
    }


    // Pagination   

    if (get_query_var('paged')) {
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    } elseif (get_query_var('page')) {
        $paged = get_query_var('page');
    } else {
        $paged = 1;
    }


    // Post Query   

    $args=array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => $cats,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 0,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order,
    'meta_key' => $meta_key,
    'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
    'offset' => $offset
    );

    $featured_query = new wp_query($args); $counter = "";

    ob_start(); ?>


    <!-- BEGIN POST WRAPPER -->

    <div class="post-wrapper <?php echo $name.' '.$spacing; ?>">


        <!-- BEGIN HEADER -->

        <?php if($header) { ?><h3 class="featured-header" style="border-color: <?php echo $color; ?>;"><?php echo $header; ?><?php if($rss) { ?><a href="<?php echo $rss; ?>" class="icon-rss"></a><?php } ?></h3><?php } ?>

        <!-- END HEADER -->


        <?php while ($featured_query->have_posts()) : $featured_query->the_post(); $counter = $counter + 1;


        // Image Dimensions

        if(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_thumbnail_width', true) && get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_thumbnail_width', true)) {
            $image_width = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_thumbnail_width', true);
        } else {
            $image_width;
        }
        if(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_thumbnail_height', true) && get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_thumbnail_height', true)) {
            $image_height = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_thumbnail_height', true);
        } else {
            $image_height;
        }


        // Image Dimensions For Mobiles

        if($image_width <= 460 && get_option($dirname.'_responsive') == "0") {
            $image_ratio = 460 / $image_width;
            $new_image_width = $image_width * $image_ratio;
            $new_image_height = $image_height * $image_ratio;
        } else {
            $new_image_width = $image_width;
            $new_image_height = $image_height;
        }


        // Columns

        if($counter %$cols == 1) {
            $first_column = " first-column ";
        } else {
            $first_column = "";
        }

        if($cols > 1) {
            $columns = " post-columns ";
        } else {
            $columns = "";
        }

        $col_width = (100 - (($cols -1) * 4)) / $cols;


        // Total Score

        if(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_total_score', true) > 0) {
            $total_score_width = (get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_total_score', true) / $gp_settings['star_number']) * 100;
        } else {
            $total_score_width = 0;
        }

        ?>


            <!-- BEGIN POST -->

            <div <?php post_class('post-loop'.$first_column.$columns); ?> style="width: <?php echo $col_width; ?>%;">


                <!-- BEGIN IMAGE -->

                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail() && $images == "true") { ?>
                    <div class="post-thumbnail<?php if($image_wrap == "true") { ?> wrap<?php } ?>">

                        <?php if(($link == "image" OR $link == "both") && get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_link_type', true) != "None") { ?>
                            <a href="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_link_type', true) == "Lightbox") { if(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_custom_url', true)) { echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_custom_url', true); } else { echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); }} else { if(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_custom_url', true)) { echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_custom_url', true); } else { the_permalink(); }} ?>"<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_link_type', true) == "Lightbox") { ?> rel="prettyPhoto[<?php echo $name; the_ID(); ?>]"<?php } ?>>
                        <?php } ?>

                            <?php $image = aq_resize(wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)), $new_image_width, $new_image_height, true, true); ?>

                            <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_link_type', true) == "Lightbox") { ?>
                                <span class="lightbox-hover icon-plus"></span>
                            <?php } ?>

                            <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_width; ?>" alt="<?php if(get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true)) { echo get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); } else { echo get_the_title(); } ?>" />       

                        <?php if(($link == "image" OR $link == "both") && get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_link_type', true) != "None") { ?></a><?php } ?>

                    </div>                  

                    <?php if($image_wrap == "false") { ?><div class="clear"></div><?php } ?>

                <?php } ?>

                <!-- END POST -->


                <!-- BEGIN LIGHTBOX IMAGES -->

                <?php $args = array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'numberposts' => -1, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'asc', 'post__not_in'   => array(get_post_thumbnail_id())); $attachments = get_children($args); if($attachments) { foreach ($attachments as $attachment) { ?>

                    <a href="<?php if(get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_gp_video_url', true)) { ?>file=<?php echo get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_gp_video_url', true); } else { echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID); } ?>" rel="prettyPhoto[<?php echo $name; the_ID(); ?>]" title="<?php echo $attachment->post_content; ?>" style="display: none;"><img src="" alt="<?php echo $attachment->post_title; ?>"></a>

                <?php }} ?>

                <!-- END LIGHTBOX IMAGES -->


                <!-- BEGIN POST TEXT -->

                <div class="post-text"<?php if(has_post_thumbnail() && $images == "true" && $image_wrap == "true") { ?> style="margin-left: <?php echo $image_width + 20; ?>px;"<?php } ?>>


                    <!-- BEGIN TITLE -->

                    <?php if($title == "true") { ?><h2 style="margin-top:-10px;"><?php if($link == "title" OR $link == "both") { ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo the_title_limit($title_length); ?>"><?php } ?><?php echo stripslashes(do_shortcode(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_hometeamname', true))); ?> VS <?php echo stripslashes(do_shortcode(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_awayteamname', true))); ?><?php if($link == "title" OR $link == "both") { ?></a><?php } ?></h2><?php } ?>

                    <!-- END TITLE -->


                    <!-- BEGIN SCORE META -->

                    <?php if($score == "true" && get_post_meta($post->ID, '_'.$dirname.'_total_score', true) > 0) { ?>

                        <div class="score-meta">    

                            <span class="gp-stars-wrapper" style="width: <?php echo (19.6 * $gp_settings['star_number']); ?>px;"><span class="rating-unselected"><span class="rating-selection" style="width:<?php echo $total_score_width; ?>%"></span></span></span>
                        </div>  

                    <?php } ?>

                    <!-- END SCORE META -->


                    <!-- BEGIN POST META-->

                    <?php if($meta == "true" && ($meta_date == "true" OR $meta_author == "true" OR $meta_cats == "true")) { ?>

                        <div class="post-meta">

                            <?php if($meta_date == "true" OR $meta_author == "true" OR $meta_cats == "true") { ?>                   



                                <?php if($meta_date == "true") { ?><span class="meta-date">Match Date: <?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></span><?php } ?>
                                <br />

                                <?php if($meta_cats == "true") { ?><span class="meta-cats">Game Type: <?php the_category(', '); ?></span><?php } ?>

                            <?php } ?>

                        </div>

                    <?php } ?>

                    <!-- END POST META-->


                    <!-- BEGIN POST CONTENT -->

                    <?php if($content_display == "full") { ?>   


                    <?php } else { ?>


                    <?php } ?>

                    <!-- END POST CONTENT -->


                    <!-- BEGIN POST TAGS -->

                    <?php if($meta == "true" && $meta_tags == "true") { ?>
                        <?php the_tags('<div class="meta-tags"><span>'.__('Tags', 'gp_lang').':</span>', '', '</div>'); ?>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <!-- END POST TAGS -->


                </div>

                <!-- BEGIN POST TEXT -->


            </div>

            <!-- BEGIN POST -->


            <?php if($cols > 1 && $counter %$cols == 0) { ?><div class="clear"></div><?php } ?>


        <?php endwhile; ?>


        <?php if($pagination == "true") { ?>
            <?php gp_pagination($featured_query->max_num_pages); ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php } ?>


    </div>

    <!-- END POST WRAPPER -->


<?php

    $output_string = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean(); 

    wp_reset_query();

    return $output_string;

}

add_shortcode("posts", "gp_posts");

?>
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

About 1/3rd of the way down you should see...

```
'post_type' => 'post',
```

Change that to `'post_type' => 'football',`

However, that code uses a number of parameters and does a lot of work that may not be applicable to your post type, and may even conflict with it or the functionality that you want. That is a lot of code to scan and just looking at it I can't tell if that one change will be adequate but it is the change that will make the query pull from your `football` post type.

Comment: I did try that, but it didn't display anything.. not even the featured image.

Comment: If you can hack the full code for me im willing to pay a price!

Comment: Sorry, no time. I am not for hire in that way.

Comment: Ok, if anyone else can do this for me.. please help